# phalcon phql fetch vs fetch all

Tags: sql, phalcon

i am getting a fetchAll when using PHQL.

is there anyway to set it to just a fetch?

```
$result = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery ( $phql , [ "id" => $id ] );
```

i have to set the results to:  `return $result[0];`

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$phql = "SELECT * FROM \Models\News AS n WHERE n.id = :id:";
$singleResult = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, ['id' => 3])->getFirst();
```